# Angular 2 iframe on website

Tags: angular, angular2-cli

Is it possible to launch angular2 cli 4.0 into an iframe on a website, in order to have a preview of angular2 components? I would be grateful for an answer to this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could run an angular app and load it into iframe. In your app, you should create a route where only one component will be visible. Then you can load it into iframe in the other website.

Example: your component would be available at `http://localhost:4200/components/card`

and then on your website, you can load it like this:
`<iframe src="http://localhost:4200/components/card></iframe>`

Comment: Is it possible to Load an angular app in a div?

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you angular app is hosted at `http://localhost:4200` which is the default url when you run the app with `ng serve`

Just add `<iframe src='http://localhost:4200'>` in you web app and angular app will be loaded inside you website.